# knockout.js binding different items to different li

Tags: knockout.js

I have a  viewModel  which contains multiple objects at different indexes

```
[0]{id=1,name="adventure",description="abc"}

[1]{id=2,name="urban",description="def"}

[2]{id=3,name="romantic",description="ghi"}
```

I got this viewModel using Mapping plugin of knockout i.e

```
var categoriesViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Now I have a html with 3 li tags as given below..

```
<section class="categories">

                <ul class="categories-list">
                    <li class="urban"><a  href="javascript:;"><span>urban living</span></a></li>
                    <li class="adventure"><a href="javascript:;"><span>adventure</span></a></li>
                    <li class="romantic"><a href="javascript:;"><span>romantic</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

How Can I bind different object to different li.

For example first li should be binded with second object from categoriesViewModel i.e categoriesViewModel ()[1] .

I do not want to hardcode index like [1],[2] etc. I want to get the relevent object from categoriesViewModel  and bind it .

Looking forward for quick help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a foreach loop:

```
<ul class="categories-list" data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <li data-bind="attr: {class: name}"><span data-bind="text: desc"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but every li has different class. and category name is not necessarily be the the same as css class. and i want to bind data so that I can use it on mouse over

Comment: That's ok. The css class name has to come from somewhere though. If you can;t put it in your viewmodel, then you can write a method in your viewmodel to return it and set it in the binding. I would not hard code it though. You can bind the mouseover event either through jquery handlers or you can use the event binding in knockout ... event: {mouseover: doSomething}

Comment: can I not use $data instead of foreach i.e every li has its own binding ?

Comment: If you have an object (not an array) and you want to access each by property, you could do that. In that case you would have every <li> listed manually though. It depends on how your data is shaped.

Comment: I have kind of restriction to read the relevent category from $data and bind it with the li.How can I do this ?

Comment: can you show your full data and what you want it to do? perhaps in a fiddle so we can help better?

Comment: This is how my categoriesViewModel looks http://screencast.com/t/nR10T4j9C6G , Now how can I extract the relevant category from the $data and bind it with li ?